Plausibility of results for PCR/PLSR daily stock return forecasting
I'm working on a project for my master's degree and, I am not sure, whether the results I'm getting are plausible or not.
I am basically trying to create a model for forecasting S&P 500 return daily.
My project is based on the following article: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417416305115
Using the same methodology as in the article, I created a PCR and PLSR model regressing y_t on x_t.


So far so good, the results are plausible. I ran the model on a test dataset and the results were fine.
But then it occurred to me, that what I am really looking for is regressing yt on x_t-1, to predict the return on the following day with the available data today.
I made the adjustment in my data by removing the first row of the target variable and the last row of the independent variables, and ran the models again.
This time, however, I am getting pretty bad results, and I am not sure whether it could be a problem with my code or what changes I should make to improve my models.


Here is a list with the data that I used:

This is my first post in this forum. If I missed something, just let me know and I'll be glad to correct it.
Thanks!

Welcome to Cross Validated! Much of financial economics would say that what you’re trying to do is basically impossible. While that does not preclude buggy code, poor performance should not be surprising.

Hi Dave, thanks!
Could you please give some pointers here about what I should read about the financial economics to better understand why this is impossible?
I am doing my master in economics/econometrics with a more hands-on approach. Since I am an engineer, my knowledge of economic theory is somewhat lacking

“Markets are efficient” is the quote you will hear. If you want to ask about that in more detail, we have a Stack dedicated to economics.

You certainly have an uphill battle searching for a market anomaly in the daily returns on the highly-liquid S&P 500. Most market anomalies (momentum, value/reversal etc) are found in longer-period returns (monthly, quarterly, etc). A reasonable starting point is that markets are on average efficient, but it is best to have some sort of rationale for the type of anomaly you are trying to detect when designing your project. Various factor models have been devised to "explain" some anomalies, but their interpretation remains unclear.
